# MeteorJS: Download file from s3 to meteor machine and upload after modification

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-s3

I am trying to write a small meteor app (called conversion server) that supports our main app with some conversion of Images and Videos.

Therefor I need to download a (potentially big) file from Amazon AWS S3 Storage to the ec2 instance, the conversion server runs on, manipulate it, upload it back to s3 and delete it from the local instance.

The manipulation is done by asynchronous exec calls to ffmpeg, the queue is stored in the database a Meteor.setInterval checks if there are new jobs.

My Problem is:

How can I Download and Upload files from and to S3 with meteor (ideally Streamed as the conversion machines do not have that much ram to download a 2GB video in one piece)

Comment: there are s3 packages for Meteor https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-aws-sdk ,  that should allow you to use GET Object and PUT Object for your s3 resources.    Alternatively, Amazon Elastic Transcoder keeps adding more and more formats, http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/ .

Comment: Thanks, both of your links are helpful. How do I do an upload or download with aws-sdk for meteor? Lets say, I have the local file /var/queue/video1.mp4 and want to upload it to a bucket in s3 how would I do that? How could I download another video from s3 to lets say /var/queue/video2.mp4? This would answer my question.

Comment: If you are transferring from s3 <-- >the Meteor app server, once you have the Amazon S3 sdk setup,  you can use getObject (for download) and putObject (for upload):   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property

Comment: @looshi If you are transferring from s3 <-- >the Meteor app server, once you have the Amazon S3 sdk setup, you can use getObject (for download)

Will it work if the file I am trying to download is not in my S3 or lets say it is not at all at S3?

Comment: @PawanSingh , no, `getObject` is specific to s3.

Comment: @looshi Its Ok thanks anyway